# `Cjhebrew` font not found

Tags: compilation-error

With TeXLive, under Ubuntu the following code compiles correctly. However, the same code does not compile under Win10, MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6354 (1.40.18) (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit).
Could you help me with this problem?

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\cjRL{.sElEm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error message:

> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The
>   rcjhblsm source file could not be found. The log file hopefully
>   contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>
> C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log
>   You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK
>   font rcjhblsm could not be created. The log file hopefully contains
>   the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>
> C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
>   You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

The respective log files:

### miktex-makemf.log

> 2018-02-23 20:53:48,432+0100 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose rcjhblsm
>   2018-02-23 20:53:48,448+0100 FATAL miktex-makemf - The rcjhblsm source file could not be found.

### miktex-makepk.log

> 2018-02-23 20:53:48,307+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with
>   command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makepk.exe" --enable-installer --verbose rcjhblsm 657 600 magstep(0.5)   2018-02-23 20:53:48,307+0100 INFO 
>   makepk - Trying to make PK font rcjhblsm at 657 DPI...   2018-02-23
>   20:53:48,323+0100 INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
>   2018-02-23 20:53:48,323+0100 INFO  makepk - Running
>   miktex-makemf.exe...                    2018-02-23 20:53:48,323+0100
>   INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose rcjhblsm
>   2018-02-23 20:53:48,479+0100 INFO  makepk - Running
>   miktex-ttf2pk.exe...                    2018-02-23 20:53:48,479+0100
>   INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe -q -t rcjhblsm
>   2018-02-23 20:53:48,713+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font rcjhblsm
>   could not be created.

Note:

It doesn't find `rcjhbltx` source neither.

Comment: Try if it works if you run once `updmap` on a command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hooray, It worked! What is it doing exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message normally means that your font map-files are not up-to-date.

Run

```
updmap
```

on a command line. (`updmap` = update map).